# How to create P2P Android Remote application?

Tags: android, remoting, p2p

I would like to develop a Remote application for Peer-to-peer Android Device using TCP/IP connection. once one of the device successfully remote to the other, he/she will be able to see what the other device is doing (example : doing drawing with an application, etc).
Is this possible to do or there is other way that is more efficient to do ? Any reference/road map is appreciated. code samples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here have pair of projects implementing a remote service and a client for it:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteService/
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClient/

I think this can help you..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If remote means on the LAN, you can use IP multicasting. If remote means the WAN, then you'll need a fully fledge P2P framework, with NAT traversal solutions, such as JXTA for example. Google JXTA and you will find info, including code samples. It is not the only solution, you could explore JGroups too.

There are UDP based P2P frameworks too. These are a bit better at NAT traversal, but you're left with the duty of putting the pieces of the puzzle (i.e., data slicing) back together.